# SQL Syntax Errors Encountered

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have a problem with SQL Query, I always get this warning, ("**The Compound statement SQL construct or statement is not supported.**") I think that due to the same warning and query is not working on the project .. This is my query code ..

```
IF(ISNULL((SELECT MAX(VLW_ID)+1 AS Epr1 FROM TABLE1), 0)) > (ISNULL((SELECT MAX(VLW_ID) + 1 
AS Expr1 FROM TABLE2), 0)) BEGIN SELECT ISNULL((SELECT MAX(VLW_ID)+1 AS Expr1 FROM TABLE1)
,0) END ELSE BEGIN SELECT IS NULL((SELECT MAX(VLW_ID) + 1 AS Expr1 FROM TABLE2),0) END
```

Attached still image code for the visibility to be easy to snatch ..

[Query Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DagzA.png)
thanks for the help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF(ISNULL((SELECT MAX(VLW_ID)+1 AS Epr1 FROM TABLE1), 0)) > (ISNULL((SELECT
MAX(VLW_ID) + 1 AS Expr1 FROM TABLE2), 0)) BEGIN SELECT ISNULL(               
(SELECT MAX(VLW_ID)+1 AS Expr1 FROM TABLE1) ,0) END ELSE BEGIN SELECT ISNULL(                
(SELECT MAX(VLW_ID) + 1 AS Expr1 FROM TABLE2),0) END
```

You have used a extra space in ISNULL in last SELECT, just remove that, It should work.

Comment: I made the mistake when I copied here, but unfortunately this is not a solution, I still get the same mistake

Comment: it is interesting that the local computer is working properly with this warning while the project on the installation does not work ...